# How do I get a valid Alfresco application context to create folders?

Tags: java, spring, email, alfresco

I'm modifying InboundSMTP to create folders for the new messages.  It appears that requires fileFolderService.create, with parameters for a folder content type.  Working back from that I need a ServiceRegistry, which in turn needs ApplicationContext.

Here's what I'm attempting to do:

```
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("alfresco/application-context.xml");
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = (ServiceRegistry) appContext.getBean(ServiceRegistry.SERVICE_REGISTRY);
FileFolderService fileFolderService=serviceRegistry.getFileFolderService();
FileInfo object = fileFolderService.create(nodeRef, messageSubject, ContentModel.TYPE_FOLDER);
```

However, this causes the inbound e-mails to be rejected.  I can comment out the last 3 lines and it still fails the same way, so something is wrong with my ApplicationContext call.  With even just that call in place, I get the following error (which makes no sense to me):

```
ERROR [org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean] [org.subethamail.smtp.server.Session-/2001:470:c27d:18:0:0:0:17:62204] 06300186 Email message processing failed
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 06300186 Email message processing failed
    at org.alfresco.email.server.EmailServiceImpl.processMessage(EmailServiceImpl.java:324)
    at org.alfresco.email.server.EmailServiceImpl.importMessage(EmailServiceImpl.java:180)
    at org.alfresco.email.server.impl.subetha.SubethaEmailServer$Handler.processDelivery(SubethaEmailServer.java:223)
    at org.alfresco.email.server.impl.subetha.SubethaEmailServer$Handler.data(SubethaEmailServer.java:184)
    at org.subethamail.smtp.command.DataCommand.execute(DataCommand.java:61)
    at org.subethamail.smtp.server.RequireTLSCommandWrapper.execute(RequireTLSCommandWrapper.java:27)
    at org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler.handleCommand(CommandHandler.java:98)
    at org.subethamail.smtp.server.Session.runCommandLoop(Session.java:222)
    at org.subethamail.smtp.server.Session.run(Session.java:125)
Caused by: org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 06300185 Not all patches could be applied
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter.applyOutstandingPatches(PatchExecuter.java:111)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter$1.doWork(PatchExecuter.java:124)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter$1.doWork(PatchExecuter.java:120)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:548)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter.onBootstrap(PatchExecuter.java:128)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:56)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:209)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:180)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:303)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:911)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:428)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.sscorp.CustomFolderEmailMessageHandler.addAlfrescoContent(CustomFolderEmailMessageHandler.java:132)
    at com.sscorp.CustomFolderEmailMessageHandler.processMessage(CustomFolderEmailMessageHandler.java:94)
    at org.alfresco.email.server.EmailServiceImpl$3.execute(EmailServiceImpl.java:296)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:454)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:342)
    at org.alfresco.email.server.EmailServiceImpl$4.doWork(EmailServiceImpl.java:304)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:548)
    at org.alfresco.email.server.EmailServiceImpl.processMessage(EmailServiceImpl.java:307)
    ... 8 more
```

What am I doing wrong while trying to get ApplicationContext?  Or, should I try another approach/is there a *better* way to create folders programmatically in Alfresco?

Comment: Why are you creating a new Application Context? Why aren't you just fetching the existing one?

Comment: And if what you want is the `FileFolderService`, why not just alter the spring bean for your class to get that injected in? Should be simpler and safer than injecting the service registry or the whole context (which can be done with spring if needed)

Comment: How does one fetch the existing Application Context?  I've not been able to find a way to access it, so I thought I had to create my own (also, this approach is how the sample code I've been able to find does it).  That's the only reason I'm doing it this way.  Injecting the FileFolderService sounds safer, but as of yet I haven't been able to figure out the right names to inject any of these things via the Spring bean.  I've had a terrible time finding decent documentation for Alfresco, I'm doing tons of "trial and error" and source reading.  What sources do you use to figure these things out?

Comment: It's just regular spring - define a setter on your bean that takes a `FileFolderService`, then in your spring context file where you define the bean, define `FileFolderService` as one of the properties of the bean, and you're done! Fetching the application context is harder, you need to register your bean as ApplicationContextAware, in the usual spring way, but you almost never need to do that...

Comment: @Gagravarr You should make this an answer.  It's been very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost certainly don't want to get the Application Context for what you need to do!

If you want "all the common services", don't get the context. Instead, ask Spring to give you the Alfresco [ServiceRegistry](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/ServiceRegistry.html). That is available as a bean with the ID `ServiceRegistry`, and has handy getters for the main services you might want

In your case though, if you know you want the `FileFolderService`, ask spring for it for your bean! If you're overriding the `documentEmailMessageHandler` bean (for example), you'd want a bean like:

```
<bean id="documentEmailMessageHandler"
      parent="emailMessageHandlerBase"
      class="com.something.else.DocumentEmailMessageHandler">
   <property name="fileFolderService" ref="FileFolderService"/>
</bean>
```

Then in your custom implementation, provide a method `setFileFolderService(FileFolderService fileFolderService)` which saves the service for later use. Follow any standard spring tutorial if this is news to you!

If you really really do need the Spring Application Context, then follow the normal Spring pattern and have your bean class implement the [ApplicationContextAware interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html), and spring will set you the context during initialisation

Comment: Perfect.  It's been nearly 5 years now since I've done much of anything with Spring (and back then it was simple maintenance work).  It's been a struggle to get back into it, but this got me back on track.  I feel like I already understand the basics better now than I did back then!  :-)

Answer (score 2):

In this case you should not need to inject the application context.

Best practice for making modifications to email handling involves creating a custom handler. The following is the important code for defining this:

```
public class CustomFolderEmailMessageHandler extends AbstractEmailMessageHandler {

    public void processMessage(NodeRef nodeRef, EmailMessage message) {
        NodeService nodeService = getNodeService();
    }

}
```

The abstract class has a `getNodeService()` method which gives you the node service. This is the verbose version of the FileFolderService.

You should use the FolderEmailMessageHandler as a guide: https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/repository/source/java/org/alfresco/email/server/handler/FolderEmailMessageHandler.java

In order to register your message handler you need override the emailService bean:
https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Inbound_SMTP_Email_Server_Configuration#Implementing_A_Custom_Node_Handler

Comment: Good info.  I'd already gotten most of that myself, but should be a help to the next person with questions on this.  Knowing getNodeService() is available is good too, but I found using it for creating folders is a lot harder than the accepted answer.